# Movie about an old lady who takes the blame for murders committed by a serial killer

Tags: identify-this-movie

The movie begins with some statement like: this is based on a true story, but the parts that are hard to believe is the part that happened in reality! "Go figure" -- I don't remember it exactly.

The plot is about a lady who watches a lot of crime drama and is questioned by police for a crime that is committed by a serial killer. A girl is killed near her house. The lady first misleads the police into thinking her husband (or boyfriend) did the crime. They take him to jail.

Then she changes her statement and misleads police again into thinking that she was the one who did the crime. And she comes up with strong indicators that she really killed the girl.

Meanwhile, the serial killer hears about it and becomes enraged because someone else "taking credit" for his work.. He writes something about it on a bathroom door with a smiley face.

The lady is allowed to visit her family and one of her grandchildren asks her: why do you lie? 
Then she admits to the police that she was misspending them from the beginning and that she is innocent all along.

The movie ends with the police woman being friendly (at last) with her younger partner policeman.

I saw it around 2003, color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [Happy Face Murders](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0183149/combined) from 1999 with Ann Margret and Marg Helgenberger.

> An eccentric older woman (Ann-Margret) implicates her brutal & controlling lover in the murder of a young intellectually disabled girl. Absorbed with "Murder She Wrote" and "Matlock", she creates details of the murder from clues she picks up from the detectives (Marg Helgenberger, Henry Thomas) on the case. Implicating herself and sentenced to jail, she then recants her testimony. But no one believes her until clues surface from the real killer that he is still out there, has killed before, and will kill again. He signs his messages with Happy Faces.

Here are the first few minutes:

Comment: Great job. That is the one